# Ionic gives error undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.user.username') when decoding the login user token

Tags: json, authentication, ionic-framework, token, ionic4

This is part of the error message that I am getting:

```
[Error] ERROR – TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.user.username') TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.user.username')(anonymous function)checkAndUpdateView — core.js:44...
```

My login process works fine and data of the user is gotten fine, on `ionic serve` version of my app, but on ios I can see that error message, like json encoding doesn't work fine or something. Why is the JSON working fine on website, but not on the app? Here is content of `TokenService` :

```
    constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

    setToken(token) {
        this.cookieService.set("chat_token", token);
    }

    getToken() {
        return this.cookieService.get("chat_token");
    }

    deleteToken() {
        this.cookieService.delete("chat_token");
    }

    getPayload() {
        const token = this.getToken();
        let payload;
        if (token) {
            payload = token.split(".")[1];
            payload = JSON.parse(window.atob(payload));
        }

        return payload.data;
    }
```

and this is the `loginUser` function in `LoginComponent` , that is triggered on logging in:

```
loginUser() {
        this.showSpinner = true;

        this.authService.loginUser(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.tokenService.setToken(data.token);
                localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(data));

                this.loginForm.reset();

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.router.navigate(["/streams"]);
                }, 200);
            },
            err => {
                this.showSpinner = false;

                if (err.error.message) {
                    this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Now, the server side, I have this rout in routes/ directory, in node express in file `authRoutes.js`:

```
router.post('/login', AuthCtrl.LoginUser);
```

And then I have this in routes/ directory, in file `userRoutes.js`:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const UserCtrl = require('../controllers/users');
const AuthHelper = require('../Helpers/AuthHelper');

router.get('/users', AuthHelper.VerifyToken, UserCtrl.GetAllUsers);
router.get('/user/:id', AuthHelper.VerifyToken, UserCtrl.GetUser);
router.get(
  '/username/:username',
  AuthHelper.VerifyToken,
  UserCtrl.GetUserByName
);
router.post('/user/view-profile', AuthHelper.VerifyToken, UserCtrl.ProfileView);
router.post(
  '/change-password',
  AuthHelper.VerifyToken,
  UserCtrl.ChangePassword
);

module.exports = router;
```

This is the part of controller auth.js on node server side:

```
    async LoginUser(req, res) {
        if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
            return res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ message: "No empty fields allowed" });
        }

        await User.findOne({ username: Helpers.firstUpper(req.body.username) })
            .then(user => {
                if (!user) {
                    return res.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).json({ message: "Username not found" });
                }

                return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password).then(result => {
                    if (!result) {
                        return res
                            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                            .json({ message: "Password is incorrect" });
                    }
                    const token = jwt.sign({ data: user }, dbConfig.secret, {
                        expiresIn: "5h"
                    });
                    res.cookie("auth", token);
                    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ message: "Login successful", user, token });
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error is:");
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ message: "Error occured" });
            });
    }
```

Comment: Where do you have a `user` object?

Comment: hi @Sébastien . I update my server side code in the question.

Comment: I thought your error was on the JavaScript side : `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.user.username')` <-- Where do you see that error?

Comment: isee it in develop tools on safari, but it catches it from iPhone (safari catches that error from iPhone)

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the server, you have a `user` object in a component.

Comment: @Sébastien yeah, but I do not know why it works on ionic serve but not when I put it on iPhone as an app....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by transferring all the stored data from CookieService, which is the main culprit of the error, to a localStorage. Just instead of storing payload and that cookie in CookieService, just transferred it to localStorage, and I didn't have any more problems. Seems like, the simpler - the better.